# C++ cast and write unsigned int with value 10 gives 5 bytes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code leads to a binary file, which as an additional byte in front of the representation of the value 10.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int data0 = 8;
    unsigned int data1 = 9;
    unsigned int data2 = 10;
    unsigned int data3 = 11;
    std::ofstream file("test.bin", std::ios_base::out, std::ios_base::binary);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data0), sizeof(data0));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data1), sizeof(data1));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data2), sizeof(data2));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data3), sizeof(data3));
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what the hexdump of the file looks like:

```
 08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 0D 0A 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00
| 8 -> OK   | 9 -> OK   |??| 10 -> OK  | 11 -> OK
```

What's going on here with the byte in front of the 10?

Comment: `0D` is a carriage return

Comment: file is opened for binary writing, so I'm not sure where that came from. Usually that's the result of the file stream seeing 0x0A, linefeed and slapping down a 0x0D to finish the Carriage Return plus Line Feed end of line delimiter on a DOS/Windows system.

Comment: Ah ha! I see it. The comma! You wanted `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary`

Comment: Damned if I know what `ofstream` constructor overload that's calling though. I'd expect a compiler error.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary`, that's it! Now it works fine. Cheers!

Comment: The code should give an error in ISO C++ , since there is no constructor for `ofstream` taking 3 arguments. I suppose MSVC has a non-standard extension in play

Answer (score 4):

```
std::ofstream file("test.bin", std::ios_base::out, std::ios_base::binary);
```

should be

```
std::ofstream file("test.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
```

Credit goes to user4581301. See the comments of the question.